# Adding commit from one branch to another in a gradle task

Tags: gradle, grgit

My requirement is to add the last commit of branch 'A' to branch 'B'. I did some research and found out '**cherry picking**' can be a good solution to this.I want to write a gradle task which will be doing this operation. So, I do something like this:

```
task CopyCommits() <<{
def grgit = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open(dir: project.parent.projectDir)
grgit.checkout(branch: 'B')
'git cherry-pick 2133467'.execute().text.trim()
```

}

Branch A is my local branch.
The above task doesn't perform the required operation.

Comment: do pull origin master from dev branch to obtain changes from your master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to use cherry-pick here since I want to push all commits to the other branch. this worked for me here:

```
task PushChanges() <<{
 def grgit = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open(dir: project.parent.projectDir)
'git push origin A:B'.execute().text.trim()
}
```